# Using Commit command With Git & Github in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am trying to upload an HTML file for a Github repository. I am trying to commit using Visual Studio Code's GUI.

I wil explain what I have done so far.

1. Created a Git repository. i.e. PHP_Development
2. Repository URL. https://github.com/ChiranthakaJ/PHP_Development.git
3. Added the folder in my PC where my source codes are located. i.e. D:\MyDev\PHP-Dev
4. Added a remote repository location named 'MyPHPDev'& added the repository URL as for the remote location.
5. Then I tried to do the initial commit using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key combination. Unfortunately it didn't go as planned and instead I got an error like the below screenshot.

   [image]
6. Then I did a small edit to the same file and tried to commit again and got the same error message as the above.

   7. However the 'Stage changes' were captured properly. Please refer the below screenshot as well.

[image]

8. Please refer the screenshot of the 'Git Log'.

[image]

I can't understand what I have done wrong here?

Please help me.

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: It looks like you've turned on [commit signing](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/signing-commits) somewhere, `commit -S`. Have you done that deliberately? There's also a config option "commit.gpgsign" - can you check you don't have that set as a local or global config option in git?

Comment: it's funny, you spent a lot of time to brush out the email on the picture, but forgot it in the log.

Comment: @Rup I have checked the repository's Master branch and the 'Require igned commits' is diabled. Then what would be the cause for this error?

Comment: I think it's something in your client side configuration, not set on the server. (If it was server configuration then you'd be able to commit OK but it would reject a push that contained unsigned commits.) In Visual Studio try Team Explorer, Project Settings, Repository Settings, Other and look for commit.gpgsign = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta tell the git client about the GPG key that you are using.
Either commit the change manually by CLI without signing the commit using the command

```
git commit
```

You can setup the GPG keys and try again. For more info on how to setup the GPG keys, you can visit [Here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification)